# Reconstruct the whitespace-omitted string in O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I want to check if my algorithm is correct.

Given a string of n characters with all white-space omitted,

```
Ex: "itwasthebestoftimes"
```

Give a dynamic programming algorithm which determines if the string can be broken into a valid sequence of words, and reconstruct a valid string with whitespaces, in O(n<sup>2</sup>).

My idea:

First find all substrings of a string (O(n<sup>2</sup>)), and for each substring map its position in space and length as an interval.

```
Ex:  "it was the best"
      [] [-] [-] [--]
       [---]  []    
          []
```

(Spaces added to make it easier to view).

In the above example, "it" is valid and gets an interval value of 2, "was" gets 3, etc. The string "twas" is also valid, and gets a value of 4.

This is then reduced to a mini-max problem to find the max non-overlaping length in the set of intervals. Since the valid string must contain all letters, the max length non-overlapping interval will be the answer, and finding this takes Theta(n*log(n)).

Therefore the solution will take O(n<sup>2</sup> + n*log(n)) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: How do you choose which substring goes to which row? When you try to put new substring into lower row because it overlaps, how do you know -- maybe by rearrangement of existing substrings in rows you could fit new substring somewhere?

Comment: Sorry about that, edited. It does NOT matter which "row" the substring goes into, it is arbitrary for the minimax solver. All that matters is checking if there is a collision or not which is given by the coordinates of the interval. The rows are only there to ease the visual representation

Comment: Actually, do you have any pointer to O(n log n) algorithms for finding the disjoint subset of intervals of maximum total length? It's easy to do in O(n^2) (with the same dynamic programming), but I don't see immediately (and cannot find any materials after brief search) how to do that in O(n log n). Are you sure you're not mixing this problem with finding the maximum *number* of disjoint intervals, not maximum *total length*? For maximum number greedy algorithm is O(n log n), indeed.

Comment: @avysk, here is the equivalent problem in graph form.
https://wincent.com/wiki/Computing_the_Maximum_Weighted_Independent_Set_of_a_graph_path

Comment: It's not equivalent at all, it's about linear path. For overlapping intervals the structure is more complex, and the same dynamic programming approach will give O(n^2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is fine (assuming you know an O(n log n) solution to the problem of finding a maximum set of non-overlapping intervals), and that you know a way to find the word intervals in O(n^2) time. However, I think the problem is easier than you're making it.

Create an array `W[0...n]`. `W[i]` will be 0 if there's no way to cut up the string from `i` onwards into words, and otherwise it'll store the length a word that starts a valid cutting up of strings.

Then:

```
W[i] = min(j such that W[i:j] is a word, and i+j = n or W[i+j]>0)
       or 0 if there's no such j.
```

If you keep your dictionary in a trie, you can compute `W[i]` in O(n-i) time assuming you've already computed `W[i+1]` to `W[n-1]`. That means you can compute all of `W` in O(n^2) time. Or if the maximum length of the word in your dictionary is `k`, you can do it in O(`nk`) time.

Once you've computed all of `W`, the whole string can be cut up into words if and only if `W[0]` is not 0.